# Aurora borealis forecasting, some technical details

Tags: magnetic-fields, solar-wind, geomagnetism

I have an idea to make a software tool (with some really user friendly interface) for predicting auroras on any place on Earth. I do know some physics behind the phenomenon, but only basics, like it is caused by ions (the solar wind), which interfere with an Earth's magnetic field.. and that's almost all I know.

I can use some "space weather" predictions, like [KP index](http://www.spaceweatherlive.com/en/auroral-activity/kp), but how can I calculate latitudes which are "affected" by a geomagnetic storm? As far as I understood, KP is given for a whole planet, but I need a way to calculate a position related probability of observing an aurora. Maybe I can use an angle of incidence of a solar wind on the Earth? I don't really know.
And how accurate KP predictions are on a long term? And what is a "long term" if we speak about KP indices? Hours? Days? Weeks? :)

I've read this question, [Is there any way to anticipate exceptional Aurora Borealis viewing conditions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26367/is-there-any-way-to-anticipate-exceptional-aurora-borealis-viewing-conditions), but I really would appreciate any reasonable technical details applicable to my problem.

**UPDATE**

More specific questions:
**1**. How to calculate probability of an aurora appearing at some certain coordinates, given known KP index? An example is an image from [KP index](http://www.spaceweatherlive.com/en/auroral-activity/kp) page.
**2**. How far ahead can one predict the KP index?

Comment: I think my best advice to you would be to find a better project. Space weather is characterized as "weather" for a reason. It's no more "regular" than atmospheric weather and the dynamics of it is just as complex (albeit the equations of motion are different). The way to observe great auroras is the same as for any other rare event: you go to the likely places where they exist and then you wait.

Comment: CuriousOne, thanks for an advice! But besides predictions I'd like to calculate an "aurora map", like one on a [KP index](http://www.spaceweatherlive.com/en/auroral-activity/kp) page. I've updated question to be more specific.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask the folks who are producing the KP predictions. Did you contact them?

Comment: @CuriousOne, no, I did't.. haven't thought about this, thank you again =)

Comment: @mexus - You could go the [space weather](http://science.gsfc.nasa.gov/heliophysics/spaceweather/) page at NASA.  There are a lot of people who have spent a great deal of time working on this problem.  They might be able to offer some help.  I think NOAA has a similar website for space weather as well.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I have a similar problem. I wrote an email to NOAA support, but got zero answer. Idk. maybe the support guy is not a scientist and has no idea about how the Kp index or their probability of visible aurora grid is calculated, does not really matter. I expected some sort of magnetic flux or other physical term, instead of got a Kp index from 1-10 and I have no idea what it means. Even NOAA does not write anything about how it is calculated from the measured data or I did not find that text.

Comment: @inf3rno - Kp of 10 is bad, Kp of 1 is basically the magnetosphere is off.  Note that NOAA is primarily in the business of forecasting and nowcasting stuff like this, not as much in the business of doing the fundamental research (I am not disparaging them, they just have a different mission in a lot of cases than, say, NASA).  The Kp index is one of several that attempt to numerically quantify the level of magnetic disturbances in the terrestrial magnetosphere (Dst and AE are two others, for example).

Comment: @honeste_vivere Any idea how much or detailed data they use to calculate the grid for this: https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/aurora-30-minute-forecast Don't get me wrong their data is really useful, but it could be better...

Comment: Not a clue but what little I know about NOAA stuff I would assume they try to simplify as much as possible.  Some indices list the ground stations used to calculate them, others are more inappropriately lax in their documentation.